# Custom header styles with Sass

Tags: css, sass

I am building out a page that has headers for each section that are different colors and each has an underline that is the same color as the heading text.  Because the underlines stretch from the left of the screen to the end of text, I've built them as pseudo elements (using :after). I did it this way because my content is in a container and the underlines need to stretch beyond the container.  Is there a way I can dynamically program the color and width for each header?  Right now I've got class for each header, which I know is not DRY at all, but I'm unsure about a better way to do it.

[image: first heading]

[image]

```
.header-white {
    position: relative;
    &::after {
        content: "";
        border-bottom: 2px solid $color-white;
        top:70px;
        left: -119px;
        right:0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 36.5%;
    }
}


.header {
    position: relative;
    &::after {
        content: "";
        border-bottom: 2px solid $color-quaternary;
        top:70px;
        left: -119px;
        right:0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 53.5%;
    }
}
```

As I am anticipating several more headers, this is not the optimal way to go.  Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: yes, you can do that, go and check mixins . You can pass parameters to mixins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixins to pass parameters

```
@mixin rtl( $ltr-value, $rtl-value) {
  width: $ltr-value;
  color: $rtl-value;

}
```

Below is the method to include mixins in any CSS declaration.

```
.header {
  @include rtl(100px, white);
}
```

Please follow the link for more info :https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.